# How to remove and restrict “Connect to server…”?

Tags: macos, smb, ftp, mdm

Using [MDM](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/deployment/dep1d7afa557/web), how can one remove and restrict “Connect to server…” including Command+K?

Want to make sure users cannot access local or remote servers.

Comment: The implementation steps vary on which MDM you've chosen, but this is intended by Apple to be managed and most MDM vendors will support this as it's not the new declarative style restriction that only the latest / actively developed MDM are supporting today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can craft a MDM configuration profile to restrict Finder with respect to the Connect to server menu.

This is documented here - you would set the value of the key to be false and then install the profile (manually or via MDM push):

- [Finder MDM payload settings for Apple devices](https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/finder-payload-settings-dep1c778fx7/1/web/1.0)

The October 2023 version of the [Apple Platform Deployment Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/welcome/1/web) has very good information on selecting an MDM, preparing your environment and then crafting these payloads for testing and then deployment to your fleet of Macs.

Comment: Thanks for helping out Mike!